# SQL Merging Tables Based On Multiple Matching Column Values

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to merge two game servers' tables that have this structure:

map | authid | name | time | date | ...

I would like to replace a row only if the `time` value of table2 is less than that of table1 AND ONLY if the `map` and `authid` values are BOTH the same. If the `time` values in table2 are greater, then the row from the current table (table1) should be kept untouched. Otherwise (on different `map` or `authid` values), the row from table2 should simply be appended to table1.

Comment: please provide example data and table schema information for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My way would be to
1st: create a view for replacing rows and another with the correct result set that should be appended like

--view for update 
create view ChangeTable1
as
select table2.map, table2.authid,table2.name, table2.date, table1.map as t1map, table1.authid as t1authid...from table1 to inner join table2 on table1.map=table2.map and table1.athid=table2.autid 
where table1.time>table2.time

-- view for appending 
create view Add2Table1 
select table2.map, table2.authid,table2.name, table2.date... from table2 where concat(table2.map, table2.authid) not in (select concat(table1.map, table1.authid) from table1)

-- update statement based on first view ChangeTable1
 
update ChangeTable1 set t1date=date, t1somevalue=somevalue......

-- insert Statement based an second view Add2Table1

insert into table 1 (map, authid, name, time, date, .... as select map, authid, name, time, date,... from Add2Table1


I hope this helps. I mostly do MS SQL, so there might be some syntax issues that need translation to MYSQL, Nils

If you need a permanent process doing this, you might consider putting this in a stored procedure